# Search JSON RESTful API based on user input

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a personal project wherein I'm fetching a certain JSON file (RESTful API). Then from that, the user inputs whatever they want then it will return a specific value (let's say the price).

Here's my code:

```
// FETCH JSON

fetch('http://phisix-api4.appspot.com/stocks.json')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
.then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
    })
.catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
})
```

From the code titled **'FETCH JSON'**, I was successful to get the data from the web server. I was able to console log the data.

The next activity is the user types the *name* in the HTML input box. My code is supposed to store to a variable what the user types. I was successful with this also. See my code.

```
// USER INPUT NAME

function getUserTick() {
    var x = document.getElementById('stocktickerinput').value;
}
```

Now (here's) the problem, using the the `variable x`, I am trying to search the JSON response by this code:

```
var obj = data
for (var i = 0; i <= 243; i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
  if (obj.stock[i].name == x){
    console.log('hey, i found it!')
  }
}
```

I'm not able to find return the correct value. It seems that the the code for loop in searching the data is all wrong.

see my fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c3x16d5s/1/

I'm not sure what should be done to the JSON response and how to search the user input. Anybody who could help?

Comment: Where is the arbitrary 243 coming from in your ````for```` loop? Ideally, you'll want to loop the number of elements within the ````stock```` array, assuming that your code is right.

Comment: Also, your ````variable x```` only has local scope and considering your ````for```` loop does not appear to be within that function, it will not have access to ````x````.

Comment: actually, its should be for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) but i decided to just use 243 since I don't need beyond 243.

Comment: should i declare the 'x' as global variable? or do you have a better approach?

Comment: One way, would be to declare it as global variable. But you might have the same problem with your `data` variable. You get a `data` in your promise result, and try to assign something  (what is `this.response`) to another `var data`

Answer (score 1):

Often times, initiating your variables higher up in the script is a surefire way to guarantee access to the proceeding functions.  I am making some assumptions since I can't actually see the structure of your `object` nor can I see the value of `x`, although your syntax looks correct.  Check to see if this works!

```
let x = document.getElementById('stocktickerinput').value;
let obj;

fetch('http://phisix-api4.appspot.com/stocks.json')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
.then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        obj = JSON.parse(data)
    })
.catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
})

function getUserTick() {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 243; i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching `code` value
    if (obj.stock[i].name == x){
      console.log('hey, i found it!')
    }
  } 
}

getUserTick()
```

Comment: Just noticed this line: obj = JSON.parse(data). QUESTION: does it mean that the the result of json.parse(data) is now a variable? is obj can be accessed inside the function getUserTick? Sorry for the questions...

Comment: It means you are returning the ````response ```` as the ````data```` variable, yes.  But that variable is scoped within the promise  chain, so we use a global variable to retrieve it (````obj````) and give it access to your ````getUserTick()```` function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @AttemptedMastery

Comment: @BenDaggers no problem!  Unfortunately, we can't get a response back in the fiddle, so it's hard for me to actually play with the data.  I hope this helps though!

Comment: I just noticed something, console.log(data) is working but the console.log(obj) is not. It's weird since you just declared the obj as variable. There's no error but there's no logs shown in my console. any idea?

Comment: Question - are you actually receiving the ````JSON```` when you do ````console.log(data)````?

Comment: Yes, I am. I kept on reading tutorials and watching youtube videos of same concept projects with mine and find out I'm doing everything wrong.  I found the correct approach to my this. Anyway, thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *filter* method to loop through your data and get specific content
of your json data.

So instead of *for* loop you can type this.

```
const result = obj.stock.filter(stock => stock.name == x)

if (result) {
  console.log("Found it")
}
```